# How to get HTML data that is stored on JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have some HTML data stored on JavaScript variable and I want to fetch the data from that variable

I'm trying to get it by `getElementById()` method. Please also keep it in mind that I have used same id in every `div`. I know it's not good way but there is some restriction. So I need the data from 2nd `Div`.

```js
var complexArray = "<div id="
post ">First content<\/div><div id="
post ">Second Content<\/div><div id="
post ">Third Content<\/div>";

var data = document.getElementById('post').innerHTML;
alert(data);
```

Comment: You can't use the same ID in every div, it's invalid and won't work. Use 'Classes' instead to achieve the desired result.

Comment: `document.getElementById`, unsurprisingly, searches the **document**, not some random string of HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't query in the document for something that only exists in a string variable.

Put that html string into a temporary element and query for it within that element

Change the repeating ID's to classes instead since ID's must be unique

```js
var complexArray = '<div class="post">First content<\/div><div class="post">Second Content<\/div><div class="post">Third Content<\/div>';

// create element to insert the html string into
var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
tempDiv.innerHTML = complexArray;

// query within that element
var posts = tempDiv.querySelectorAll('.post');

var data = posts[1].innerHTML;
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DOM PARSER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).And id should be unique for Every element,as you have use same id for multiple elements,which is wrong.I have change from id to class ,with `post` id is only for `first element`

```js
var complexArray = "<div id='post' class='post'>First content<\/div><div class='post'>Second Content<\/div><div class='post'>Third Content<\/div>";

let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(complexArray, "text/html");
console.log(doc.getElementById('post').innerHTML); //
/// query selector All for all elements

doc.querySelectorAll('.post').forEach((ele, i) => {
  if (i == 1) {
    console.log(ele.innerHTML)
  }

})
```